# Editing textarea breaks Droppable

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, prototypejs, scriptaculous

I'm trying to drag content into a textarea using prototype/scriptaculous, edit the text area, and then continue to drag and drop some more content. Dragging and dropping works fine, but as soon as I edit the content in the textarea, dropping ceases working.

I wrenched it down into a [test case](http://jockelhofmann.de/dragdrop.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>dragdrop testcase</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/shoppingZend/public/javascript/scriptaculous/lib/prototype.js"></script>       
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/shoppingZend/public/javascript/scriptaculous/src/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,dragdrop,controls"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content_1" class="drag">Content 1</div>
        <div id="content_2" class="drag">Content 2</div>
        <div id="content_3" class="drag">Content 3</div>
        <textarea id="drop"></textarea>
        <script>
            new Draggable('content_1', {
                revert: true
            });

            new Draggable('content_2', {
                revert: true
            });

            new Draggable('content_3', {
                revert: true
            });

            Droppables.add(
                'drop', {
                    onDrop: function(dragged, dropped, event) {
                        dropped.innerHTML += dragged.innerHTML;
                    }
                }
            );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Just in case of it being a browser problem (which I doubt it to be): I'm only using Firefox on Linux, it's a very private site and does not need to work anywhere else.

Any idea where I could start debugging?

Comment: Did you try using `dropped.value` instead of `dropped.innerHTML`? This is a form element instead of a normal container element.

Comment: What versions of prototype and scriptaculous are you using there? This works fine as is in the latest Firefox (on Mac, don't have Linux except servers) when I use the latest versions of both. Ditto on the value vs innerHTML.

Comment: @Geek Num 88: Even if it's a form element, AFAIK `textarea` has no `value` attribute. Still I'm going to try it out tonight, when I have access to it.
@Walter: Prototype JavaScript framework, version 1.7, script.aculo.us scriptaculous.js v1.9.0

Comment: It seems to be an issue with FF. I just tried it on IE and it works, but doesn't with FF on windows (FF ESR 24.3.0). I'm not sure about the exact version on Linux, but should be quite actual.

Comment: Per MDN HTMLTextAreaElement does have a value attribute https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PrototypeJS handles textarea as a form element. All form elements have a value property (ex. select, input, textarea). So, try Geek Num 88 suggestion:

```
dropped.value += dragged.innerHTML;
```

I tried in Chrome, FF and IE and it seems to work correctly.

Domus71

Comment: Great! That's the solution. I believe I would have looked in a totally different direction. Thanks a lot!